# Spray HTTPS Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify

Tags: scala, ssl, spray

Currently I am implementing a web service with Scala using Spray i/o. Looking to use SSL to secure my requests. However I am having difficulty configuring the SSL. When an https call is initiated there is an error thrown related to the handshake

```
 fatal error: 80: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
```

Created a cert using this

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias mykey  -dname "CN=dev.site.com,OU=app" -keystore keystore.jks -storepass pas -validity 365
```

Created an ssl trait like this

```
trait SSLConfiguration {

  implicit def sslContext: SSLContext = {
    val keystore = keystore.jks
    val password = pas

    val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks")
    val in = getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(keystore)
    require(in != null, "Bad java key storage file: " + keystore)
    keyStore.load(in, password.toCharArray)

    val keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509")
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, password.toCharArray)
    val trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509")
    trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore)
    val context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
    context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers, new SecureRandom)
    context
  }

  implicit def sslEngineProvider: ServerSSLEngineProvider = {
    ServerSSLEngineProvider { engine =>
      engine.setEnabledCipherSuites(Array("TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"))
  engine.setEnabledProtocols(Array("SSLv3", "TLSv1"))
      engine
    }
  }
}
```

Set up my boot to use the trait.

```
   object Boot extends App with SSLConfiguration 
//bind to io interface. set ssl engine providor
    IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(service, interface = interface, port)(sslEngineProvider)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you enable SSL in the configuration file?

```
spray.can {
  server {
    ssl-encryption = on
  }
}
```

I tried your code and slightly changed it, it worked in my laptop.
I deleted the whole 
   `implicit def sslEngineProvider`
and use default one
   `IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(service, interface = "0.0.0.0", port = 8080)`.
And do you put your keystore file in the project's resource folder (project/src/main/resources)?

Comment: This is the application.conf file in resources?

Comment: Yes, it's in application.conf.

Comment: You can add  `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake`  to get more logs

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the error message I am receiving?

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be related to the java version installed.
I faced this issue when I was installing open JDK version of java on linux machine, when I changed the java version to Oracle JDK the issue disappeared.

The exact application that threw this exception is Information Workbench (fluid ops product) and java version was 8
Using which version of java wasn't mentiond in system prerequists by fluid ops people.